# ABOUT HEADER FILE CREATION ERROR IN C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

i'm creating header file for .cpp file,where it will contain only declaration or prototype of function

here is the threes programs i have written
  1.header.h file//where i have declared functions add(*,*) and sub(*,*)

```
 #ifndef HEADER_H
 #define HEADER_H
 #pragma once
 int s;
 int add(int a,int b);
 int sub(int a,int b);
 #endif
```

2.header.cpp,where i have defined functions add(*,*) and sub(*,*)

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include "header.h"
 using namespace std;


int add(int a,int b){
s=10;   
int c=a+b+s;
return c;
}

 int sub(int a,int b){
 int c=a-b;
 return c;
 }
```

3.example.cpp

```
     #include<iostream>
     #include"header.h"
     using namespace std;
      void main(){

    int a=10,b=20;

    int c=add(a,b);
    int d=sub(c,a);

    cout<<"c"<<c;
    cout<<"d"<<d;

    //cout<<s;
    getchar();
      }
```

here, i declared variable 's' in header.h and defined in header.cpp file ,which is given as addition to variable c in example.cpp file output.

it showing error
header.obj : error LNK2005: "int s" (?s@@3HA) already defined in example.obj
Projects\header\Debug\header.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
 please help me to resolve this error,i'm working from long time for this...thanks in advance

Comment: If you use include guard #define, I think there's no point in putting `#pragma once` inside them...

Comment: but i read in internet that usage of #pragma will held to optimization of code execution ,that y i added,u mean to say i can only write,#ifndef #pragma ..endif,right?

Comment: No, the `#ifndef` and `#define` go together like you have them. The `#pragma once` is a non-standardized *alternative* to that, and may reduce compilation time for some compilers. It does not affect code execution in any way. You should probably put it outside the [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), or not use it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error, because this line in .h is already a *definition*:

```
int s;
```

You need to have this in header:

```
extern int s;
```

And then in exactly one .cpp file, usually one with same base file name as the .h file, you need to have the definition:

```
int s;
```

---

Related: You don't need the `extern` keyword with function declarations, because they're just declarations, telling compiler that such a function exists somewhere, and you can do that as many times as you like. But if you put a global (non-`static`, non-`inline`) function *definition* (with `{}` function body instead of `;`) to a .h file, you do get similar linker error about multiple definitions.

Comment: @Santhosh Cool. Here at SO, once you get answers you are satisfied with, you mark the answer you like best as accepted (the tick mark at the upper left corner of answer). This marks the question as "solved".